# Xcode 8 keyboard extension debugger

Tags: debugging, xcode8, ios-keyboard-extension

I have an app with a keyboard extension, and an iMessages extension. The main app debugs just fine, stops at breakpoints & allows stepping through code. The iMessage extension also works fine. The keyboard extension used to work fine with the debugger but ever since I installed XCode 8 it's been failing. It either fails to reach the breakpoint throwing a SIGABRT / SIGQUIT on thread 1, or it reaches the breakpoint and then crashes on the first 'step over' with a SIGQUIT.

I have Xcode 8.2.1 on OSX Sierra 10.12.3. I've tried my test device, iPhone 6, as well as the simulator. I've rebooted the dev box as well as the device. I've cleared the temporary files and cleaned the build (Shift+Command+Option+K and Shift+Command+K).

Has anyone else had any issues with debugger in XCode 8 and keyboard extensions?

TIA,
Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered this bug from new Xcode (8.2.1) project. I found a temporary solution to debug my keyboard.

1. Run your code like always!
2. Bring up your keyboard until the error (SIGQUIT) appear!
3. Goto xcode > debug > detach
4. Goto again Xcode > debug > Attach to Process: attach the keyboard (it should be first process)

Now, your breakpoints will work. but there are no log output unfortunately!
I hope it temporary solve your problem.

Comment: Thank for the fix. I didn't work the first time but after a few tries I did get it to connect successfully and continue to step through the code.

Comment: how do i get log output after attaching?